# ObservableForProperty for multiple Reactive Observable Sequence

Tags: c#, mvvm, system.reactive, reactiveui

I'm trying to **ObservableForProperty** for multiple Reactive Observable Sequences.
Here's the code.

```
using ReactiveUI;

public ReactiveUIDerivedClass<T> FName {get; private set;}
public ReactiveUIDerivedClass<T> MName {get; private set;}
public ReactiveUIDerivedClass<T> LName {get; private set;}

FName = new ReactiveUIDerivedClass<T>();
MName = new ReactiveUIDerivedClass<T>();
LName = new ReactiveUIDerivedClass<T>();
```

**Here T is System.String**. **So, the below method works.**

```
private void ObserveForPropertyInThreeFields()
{
  Observable.CombineLatest(FName.ObservableForProperty(p => p.Value),
                           MName.ObservableForProperty(p => p.Value),
                           LName.ObservableForProperty(p => p.Value))
            .Where(p => p.All(v => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v.Value)))
            .Subscribe(p => { /* do some stuff */ } );
}
```

Now, I want to achieve similar result where T for the properties are of three different types. When I used **Observable.CombineLatest**, I get the following error message.

*The type arguments for method 'System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.CombineLatest
(System.IObservable, System.IObservable, 
System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. 
Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.*

Any ideas on how do I *ObserveForProperty* Change for three properties of different types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm leaving out the specific detail of using `ObservableForProperty` here - it's only the fact that the types of the streams differ that is important, so we can look at this as a vanilla Rx problem.

If you have streams with differing types then obviously the compiler cannot merge them into a single type itself. You need to specify a result selector function as the final argument to `CombineLatest` to tell it how you want to do this: e.g. given the following source streams:

```
IObservable<T1> xs;
IObservable<T2> ys;
IObservable<T3> zs;
```

...then one easy option is to produce an anonymous type (as long as you aren't returning it outside of the function of course) e.g.:

```
Observable.CombineLatest(xs, ys, zs, (x,y,z) => new { x,y,z });
```

Answer (score 7):

This is actually built-in to ReactiveUI already, using a better method than `ObservableForProperty`, called `WhenAnyValue`:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.FName, x => x.MName, x => x.LName, 
    (first,middle,last) => new { first, middle, last });
```